How can i use class objects as parameters in other classes?
Im trying to use class an object from class Vektor as parameter for a function of my class Matrix, and in the other directon.
/////CMyVektor.h////
#pragma once
#include "CMyMatrix.h"


class CMyVektor
{
private:
    int dimension;
    double *vekArray; // Dinamishe Array

public:
    CMyVektor(){};

    CMyVektor(int dimension1);

    void set_komps();

    int get_dim() const { return dimension; };                // Dimension zuruckgeben
    void set_dim(int dimension1) { dimension = dimension1; }; // Dimension setzen

    double get_komp(int index);             // Get komp Vektor mit Index
    void set_1komp(int index, double komp); // Set ein bestimmter Komp mit index

    int get_vek();

    double laenge();

    CMyVektor operator+(CMyVektor a);

    CMyVektor operator*(double lambda);

    CMyVektor gradient(CMyVektor x, double (*funktion)(CMyVektor x));

    CMyVektor verfahren(double (*funktion)(CMyVektor x), double lambda);

    CMyVektor operator*(CMyMatrix A);

    friend class CMyMatrix;
};

/////CMyMatrix.h///////
#pragma once
#include "CMyVektor.h"


class CMyMatrix
{
    private:
        int dimM;
        int dimN;
        double **m_Matrix;

    public:
        
        CMyMatrix(int _dimM, int _dimN);
        CMyMatrix(double _00, double _01, double _10, double _11);
        int getDimM()const{return dimM;}
        int getDimN()const{return dimN;}
        void setComp(int m, int n, double wert);
        double getComp(int m, int n);

        CMyMatrix invers();
        CMyMatrix jacobi(CMyVektor x, CMyVektor (*function)(CMyVektor x));
       
       friend class CMyVektor;
};


I always get the error of "Unknown type name "CMyVektor" and "CMyMatrix".
i tried to put them together in a file so that class is before defined, but i also need to use the other class object as parameter.
i also tried to make the classes friends but i still getting same error.
i hope you can help me.

Try to google "forward declarations". That's what you need :)

First, you have to get rid of the circular includes (look it up), probably by removing both and replacing them with foward declarations. Second, every function parameter where you accept a vector/matrix by value, you should probably accept by a const reference instead. Third, unless your goal is to practice manual memory management, get rid of the raw pointers and new/malloc calls, and use std::vector or std::unique_ptr instead. (Or, if you do want to practice doing it manually, you must write destructors and copy/move constructors/assignments, otherwise your code is leaking memory).

Thanks, I saw I just needed to declare the class

Recommended reading: What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?. Scroll down to "Binary Arithmetic Operators".
